# Implementing SOLR PostFilter - How could I read configuration from customer post filter

Tags: solr

I am implementing custom SOLR PostFilter logic following the articles:
http://qaware.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-write-postfilter-for-solr-49.html
https://lucidworks.com/2015/05/15/custom-security-filtering-solr-5/

In my custom SOLR postfilter I am making database call to SQL Server and I need different connection string based on environment - dev/preprod/prod.

How could I read connection string from some configuration in SOLR?
Is it possible to extend configuration in a way so connection string is accessible for reading inside custom QueryParser?

For example, somewhere below inside **Solr.config** where custom parser is defined?

```
<queryParser name="CustomSolrPostFilter" class="CustomSolrPostFilter" />
```

Or read from **core.properties** file somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it usually happens after posting question, answer was found almost immediately.

Need to extend in parser declaration:

```
<queryParser name="CustomSolrPostFilter" class="CustomSolrPostFilter">
    <str name="myCustomConfigurationProperty">jdbc:sqlserver....</str>
</queryParser>
```

Then it could be accesible inside QParserPlugin implementation:

```
@Override
public void init(NamedList namedList) {
    namedList.get("myCustomConfigurationProperty") //give "jdbc:sqlserver...."
}
```